# Python importing issues

Tags: python, import

I am receiving the below error for my code:

> **NameError: name 'ser' is not defined**

**Mainpythonfile.py:**

```
import serial
from commands import *

############## Initializing COM -Port #####################
ser = serial.Serial()
ser.baudrate = 19200
ser.port = 'COM3'
ser.timeout = 0.1
ser.open()
print("Serial Port geöffnet: ", ser.is_open)
write("ADR 06")
```

**commands.py:**

```
def write(text):
    ser.write(bytes("{}\r".format(text), 'utf-8'))    
    #print(bytes("{}\r".format(text), 'utf-8'))
    return ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
```

What is wrong with my Code, hope you can help me :)

Comment: `ser` is not defined in commands.py?

Answer (score 0):

`commands.py` does not know about variables inside `Mainpythonfile.py`.

You could however pass variables to the functions:

**Mainpythonfile.py:**

```
ser = serial.Serial()
...
write(ser, "ADR 06")
```

**commands.py:**

```
def write(ser, text):
    ser.write(bytes("{}\r".format(text), 'utf-8'))    
    #print(bytes("{}\r".format(text), 'utf-8'))
    return ser.readline().decode('utf-8')
```

Notice how `ser` is now a parameter of the function `write` and you're passing it from your main module.

Comment: Thank you, that works.
But isn't there a more stylish way to handle the problem?
Imagine I have to use several functions from other modules in my imported module... for example the simple `import time` has to be in every module...

Comment: No, there is not. There are built-ins, like str, dict, list, ... that are known everywhere. Then there are modules, functions, variables, ..., that you need to make known to your module, either by ``import`` or by passing them as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest solution would be to add ser as an argument for `write`, and pass the instantiated ser into to when you call it in your main script.